# Biblatex, authoryear, and first name abbreviations in citations

Tags: biblatex, citing

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} %
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex} %

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @Book{pollis-schwab79a,
    editor =       {Pollis, Adamantia and Peter Schwab},
    title =        {Human Rights: Cultural and Ideological Perspectives},
    publisher =    {Praeger},
    year =         {1979}
  }      
  @Article{schwab-meijaard13,
    author =       {Schwab, Arend L. and Jaap P. Meijaard},
    title =        {A Review on Bicycle Dynamics and Rider Control},
    journal =      {Vehicle System Dynamics},
    year =         {2013},
    volume =       {51},
    pages =        {1059--1090}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

% \textcite{pollis-schwab79a}

\textcite{schwab-meijaard13}

\end{document}
```

The citation appears as

> Schwab and Meijaard (2013)

This is fine.  But uncomment now the line with % \textcite{pollis-schwab79a}.  This is what appears:

> Pollis and P. Schwab (1979)
>
> A. L. Schwab and Meijaard (2013)

Biblatex puts first name abbreviations into the citation for the duplicate name (Schwab).  I do not want this for several reasons.  How can I tell it not to do this?

Comment: Add `uniquename=false` to your `biblatex` options.